# Getting "Cannot GET /uploads/" for static file in Node js

Tags: node.js, express, es6-modules

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
import fileRoutes from "./routes/fileuploadRoutes.js"
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
// console.log((path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))
```

I Used the above code and not able to get the static uploads folder at "http://localhost:3000/uploads/" where 3000 is the port defined. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLqgE.png)

Comment: Yes i started my server

Answer (score 0):

Please that way is not correct .Using `use method` for getting your file is not correct .Instead use `get method`  to get them . This way of writting  is used to attach  [middleware](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_middleware.htm) to your express app and not used to get file .
Replace `app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))` by

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "uploads"))); // attaching middleware
```

then after get your file with :

```
app.get('/uploads' , function (req, res){
     res.send("<img src='your_file_name_in_uploads_folder'>")  //for example
})  // a endpoint that will handle your file uploading
```

Answer (score -1):

can you please try once with the following code?

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
import fileRoutes from "./routes/fileuploadRoutes.js"
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
// console.log((path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))
```

Comment: That's not working

Comment: what is port number on which your express server is running?

Comment: on 3000 port and it was running

Comment: can you add that code which starts your express server?

Comment: const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/Images_Testing",(err) => {
    if(!err){
        console.log("DataBase Connected Successfully");
    }
    else{
        console.log(err);
    }
});
app.use("/images", fileRoutes)
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server Started at 3000"))

Comment: express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads'))

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood what you are trying to say , can you elaborate

Comment: what does express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')) this returns? Is it returning any file?

Comment: this was logged in console when i tried to print it " [Function: serveStatic]"

Comment: no, I mean is there any file like `/uploads/index`?

Comment: Yes, there is uploads and there were image files in the folder  there was nothing like index file/folder in uploads folder

Comment: you can not serve static file like this. You need to use like `/uploads/${filename}`

Comment: yeas in react front end , i  did same thing --- <img src={`http://localhost:3000/${eachImage.filePath}`} alt="siglefiles"/> ---,  and the requested url for the api call is "http://localhost:3000/uploads/2022-08-23T05-15-46.665Z-1.png"

Comment: Maybe we can connect via WebEx or Google meet  to check if you are okay , I can provide my gmail

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer, finally tried with axios api call

Comment: That's not an answer, you could leave that as a comment for your own post or for one of the answers you got.